# css responsive design having difficulty accessing width with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, width

I am making my first responsive design website.. I have an image slider div that is set with using pixels and media queries. I want to be able to access the width so I can tell the image slider how far I need to move. Unfortunately media queries don't seem to change the HTML. Is there any workarounds to get that information so I can use it in javascript.

here is a simple webpage example to play with and a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/synthet1c/sNbW9/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

<style>

    body{
        position:absolute;
        background:red;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    #outer{
        position:absolute;
        width:80%;
        height:80%;
        background:red;
        background-image:url('http://www.largepictures.net/largepictures/scenery/largepictures_scenery_large_3066.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        margin:auto;
    }

    #inner{
        width:80%;
        height:80%;
        background:rgba(255,0,0,0.3)
        margin:auto;
        margin-top:5%;
    }

</style>

    <script>

    document.getElementById('inner').onclick = function(){
        alert(document.getElementById('inner').style.width);
    }

    </script>   

</head> 

<body>

    <div id="outer">

        <div id="inner">click the box to get width</div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `element.style` object is only available for properties set with the `style` attribute (as the name might suggest). To retrieve CSS settings for elements whose style is set using a stylesheet:

```
document.getElementById('inner').onclick = function(){
    alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('inner'), null).width);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sNbW9/1/).

References:

- [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 0):

I made a little snippet for myself as this is a function I have been needing for a while

```
var comStyle = function(element , pseudoElt){ 
    if(!pseudoElt){pseudoElt = null} 
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(element), pseudoElt); }
```

This has me thinking though... Am I able to change the prototype so if element.style.something equals and empty string then use getComputedStyle() to get the actual value from the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `offsetWidth`, it's read-only property providing width of an element as an integer.

```
var el = document.getElementById('inner')

el.onclick = function(){
      alert(el.offsetWidth)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2r7jnb4/